# How to compare two bool type values in the list in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, model-view-controller

I have a list of type bool. I'm checking a condition, if condition is true result(i mean true) will be added to the list and same for the else part. Now i want to compare those two bool values in list and get the final value to assign it to a variable.

i have used the below code, but while assigning the value to the variable am getting some error.

```
var temp1= new List<bool>();
            fObject.ForEach((f) =>
                {
                    if (condition)
                    {
                        temp1.Add(true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        temp1.Add(false);
                    }

                });
                         var value = (from p in temp1
                                      from q in temp1
                                      select p && q);

                    model.IsTempVariable = value;
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you explain the underlying problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Why do you set the `model.IsTempVariable` inside the loop?

Comment: it is by mistake i have typed. i have corrected it below.. can you please suggest solution?

Comment: The object 'f' must have a method for comparing two items.  what if you 'f'.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need that list or any other temp var for this specific scenario if all you do in the loop is check the condition:

You could replace all of the code with simple [`All`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
model.IsTempVariable = fObject.All(f=> the condition);
```

If you are doing other stuff in the loop then use a temp var like so:

```
bool tempVar = true;
foreach (f in fObject)
{
    .. your other stuff ...
    if (!condition) tempVar = false;
}
model.IsTempVariable = tempVar;
```

And if you really must have a list then again check with `All` if all the values are true:

```
model.IsTempVariable = temp1.All(b=>b);
```

Comment: i'm in need of not modfying the foreach block and if condition. whithout changing them can i get alternate solution?

Comment: Yes, look at the last line of my answer. this goes immediately after the loop instead of the current linq query you have.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with your code properly formatted:

```
var temp1= new List<bool>();
fObject.ForEach((f) =>
{
  if (condition)
  {
    temp1.Add(true);
  }
  else
  {
    temp1.Add(false);
  }
});
var value = (
  from p in temp1
  from q in temp1
  select p && q);

model.IsTempVariable = value;
```

Simplifying (I'll assume condition is a bool expression which depends on f):

```
var temp1= fObject
   .Select(f => condition)
   .ToList();
var value = (
  from p in temp1
  from q in temp1
  select p && q);

model.IsTempVariable = value;
```

From here, removing the vars will show the problem:

```
List<bool> temp1= fObject
   .Select(f => condition)
   .ToList();
IEnumerable<bool> value = (
  from p in temp1
  from q in temp1
  select p && q);

model.IsTempVariable = value;
```

The error (which you should have included in the question), is that IsTempVariable (probably a `bool`) cannot be assigned a `IEnumerable<bool>` value.

The answer is: stop using var and you'll understand your types and make correct decisions.

---

Here's how I would write the code for two items:

```
Customer item1 = fObject[0];
Customer item2 = fObject[1];
Func<Customer, bool> condition = f => conditionExpression;
model.IsTempVariable = condition(item1) && condition(item2);
```